# How to make a usual latex installation compile the following non-standard array-syntax?

Tags: arrays, incompatibility, preamble

Once I seem to have worked on a system where, for some reason, latex code containing

```
     $\array{a & b \\ c & d }$
```

seems to have worked. (Note that, in particular, the "alignment" options of the {rcrcr} kind, standard in the usual 
\begin{align} \end{align} construction, is missing here.
Now I need to compile this on what is a more or less standard latex installation, and it does not compile as is. Of course, one option would be to edit everything into the standard \begin{align} \end{align}.

Question: can you recommend an alternative, so as to be able to compile such code with as little editing overhead as possible? Some package or option in the preamble?

Comment: I don't think this can have ever worked. Probably you confuse `\array` with `\matrix`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the syntax at all, just [re]define `\array`, but I would not do that, as `array` is a widely used beginning to the `array` environment of LaTeX.  I would rename it as `\myarray`, which can be defined to be an aligned TABstack.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\newcommand\myarray{\alignCenterstack}
\TABstackMath
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}% inter-row baselineskip
\setstackaligngap{1em}% horizontal gap between align groups
\begin{document}
$\myarray{a =& b \\ c =& d }$\quad
$\myarray{y =& mx + b \\ E =& mc^2 }$ or this
$\myarray{a =& b & y =& mx + b\\ c =& d& E =& mc^2 }$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Useful solution, thank you. I marked it as answered since the portions of my "legacy" code I had been testing so far worked with your method. Now (working incrementally) I reached a place where I used the \overset{}{}     command, and suddenly there are error messages, in particular "Missing control sequence inserted. <inserted text> \inaccessible". Do you know a solution to this, from these information alone? (I know that one possibly should isolate the problem and post a minimal non-working example, but I am checking first whether there is a quick "the reason must be this or that" solution.)

Comment: @PeterHeinig I would have to see some code, though mabe all you need is to include the `amsmath` package.  Unfortunately, I am going offline for a few days, starting NOW!

Answer (score 0):

As @egreg has already pointed out in a comment, you may be thinking of the `\matrix` command. For sure, the following code, which sets up a macro called `\myarray`, compiles properly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' environment
\newcommand\myarray[1]{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}
\begin{document}
$\myarray{a & b \\ c & d }$
\end{document}
```